# Data Binding in ListBox WP7 error, platform C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, textblock

I try to use data binding to add to ListBox in WP7, using C#. But it seems not working and I totally don't know why. Just only row's border is drawn and text's content doesn't display.

Here is a class i want to add to

```
 public class ResultTemplate
    {
        public string Mealname;
        public string CanteenID;
        public DateTime Date;
    }


public class View
{
    List<ResultTemplate> result;
   //....
    void Load()
    {
       this.listbox.ItemSource = result;
    }
}
```

My XAML code :

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="searchlist" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="searchlist_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF807C7C" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel MinHeight="60" Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text="{Binding Mealname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25" Width="385" />
                                    <!--<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="50" Width="50"/>-->
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="textblock2" Text="{Binding CanteenID}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF004AFF"/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="textblock3" Text="{Binding Date,StringFormat=dddd.dd/MM/yyyy}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF00AB00"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Property `ObservableCollection` for the binding resource not List OR implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: But in another case it still works right? So why do we should use this?

Comment: Because this is the proper way to do data binding